# Topic branches when working with a remote

Tags: git, github, repository, branch

I am currently using a github repo to manage my work. In general, if I create a topic branch that only I am working on, should I push it to the origin repo? What is the usual convention?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480723/dvcs-how-often-and-when-to-commit-changes

Answer (score 1):

If no one else needs to work on it, then there's no need to push it, it's just as functional staying just in your local repository.

The only reason you may want to push it up is if you don't have a local backup strategy, and pushing is your backup (which isn't a good idea to rely on). Though this could eventually lead to a lot of unnecessary branches on the remote repository.

Comment: One way to avoid remote clutter is to push into a different namespace on the remote, e.g. `refs/justin/heads/feature` or `refs/justin/feature` instead of the usual `refs/heads/feature`.

Answer (score 1):

Even if no one else is working on it, you might want to make it publicly available, just in case people want to look at it, for inspiration, or because they're curious what new features are coming down the pipeline, or whatever. Then after you merge it into master, you can delete it. Or not. It doesn't matter much, except that you might eventually end up with zillions of branches.