# How can I restore a python file I deleted through NERDTree, the vim file manager extension?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I have deleted a python file I thought I wouldn't need in NERDTree. I can't locate the file in system Trash to restore. Is there any where the file still resides? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

NERDTree did `rm -rf filename` (Unix) or `rmdir /s /q filename` (Windows). Those commands don't interact with your system's trash so you can consider `filename` gone forever.

Comment: The lesson being, [commit often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715628/in-git-why-is-it-good-to-commit-often) (and use version control, of course)